# Getting the upload file content to wsgi

Tags: python, wsgi

I'm writing a simple wsgi script for upload a file. Using html form.

Following is the wsgi script,

```
import os
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()


class upfile(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.errors = []


    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):


        f = open(os.path.join(self.script_dir, 'upload.html'))
        self.output = f.read()
        f.close()

        self.response_content_type = 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'
        fields = None
        if 'POST' == environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] :        
            fields = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'],environ=environ, keep_blank_values=1)
            fileitem = fields['file']
            fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename) 
            open('uploads/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())


        self.output = self.output % {"filepath":str(fields)} # Just to see the contents

        response_headers = [('Content-type', self.response_content_type),('Content-Length', str(len(self.output)))]
        status = '200 OK'
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [self.output]

application = upfile()
```

Then in my HTML form I put a file field as usual,

```
<input type='file' name='file' />
```

My problem is fields (cgi.FieldStorage) is having only the file name. No file contents. I want the file content to uploading not only the file name.

Following is the value coming to the fields variable,

`"FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('file', 'CatchSkull-large.jpg'), MiniFieldStorage('email', 'chamith@gmail.com'), MiniFieldStorage('operation', 'Upload'), MiniFieldStorage('current', 'upload')])"`

Please ignore other fields they are other fields on the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While it's very commendable that you're trying to write this from scratch, i would use something like Flask for WSGI applications, in general.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I figured out the answer. I missed to put the enctype on the HTML form,

```
<form id="upload" name="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then all the things gone OK.

Thanks.